# Simple Python Regex Substitution

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, url

I'm attempting to change a portion of a url using the re.sub() function in python. I assumed it was straightforward, but it doesn't seem to modify my test string in any way.

I have:

```
line = '        <h3><a href="40_On-Site_Storage_High_Lift_Pumping_Caustic_Storage/31-BUV-4021/DETAILS/31-BUV-4021.pdf" target="'

out_line = re.sub(r'href="[\w,_]*/','href="30_Actiflo_and_Filters/', line)
```

When I print out_line I end up with the exact same string. My intention is to replace the section between 'href="' and '/' with '30_Actiflo_and_Filters'.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to replace from `href` to the last `/` or the first `/`? And also I see a comma in the character class, obviously there is no comma in your string so it won't match anything.

Comment: First /. Even without the comma it doesn't work however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out = re.sub(r'href=".*?/', 'href="30_Actiflo_and_Filters/', line)` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Anyone know why \w doesn't match as I expected (any alphanumeric characters)?

Comment: _ is not an alphanumeric character, and as @Psidom said in the comment, there aren't any commas in your string, so there wouldn't be any matches. The period matches any character, and I used the `?` to match the first `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your regex is not working is that your url contains character `-` which is not included and also you don't need comma in the character class, so `[\w_-]*` should work fine:

```
re.sub(r'href="[\w_-]*/','href="30_Actiflo_and_Filters/', line)
# '        <h3><a href="30_Actiflo_and_Filters/31-BUV-4021/DETAILS/31-BUV-4021.pdf" target="'
```

Besides if you want to match to the first `/`, use a exclude `^` character will be more handy:

```
re.sub(r'href="[^/]*/','href="30_Actiflo_and_Filters/', line)
# '        <h3><a href="30_Actiflo_and_Filters/31-BUV-4021/DETAILS/31-BUV-4021.pdf" target="'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and sweet solution:

```
outline = re.sub(r'(is)href="(.*?)/','30_Actiflo_and_Filters/',str(line))
```

Since your targetted string is alphanumeric, `\w` won't help. You may try `[0-9a-zA-Z]*`.